# Electric fields in a galvanic cell

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, electricity

I have read hat there is two types of electric fields exist in galvanic cell.I understand E because of charges accumulated on electrodes but what about other E -field? What does cause this field and what is the direction? Detailed answer with explanation in terms of ions and charge will be helpful.

Full thought and Reasoning : In a galvanic cell when we immerse electrodes in solution,both electrode get charged.This building of charges is the result of chemical reactions on both sides. Now we in this process of building charges on the electrode if we see individual electrode ,lets say on one electrode there is negative charge (-ve) is building due to chemical reaction.This reaction also result in extra metal ions in solution which will be equilibrium with the electrode in joining the it and again separating with it again. Now I have understood till now .I know that there will be electric field between electrode due to these charges built  on electrodes.My question is what about the ions in the solution of negative electrode(-ve ) side  and lack of ions on the positive electrode side ? Will there be any Electric field from Positive to Negative electrode due to these ions (there are in different solution & different beakers )?
Example : Let's say We have a circuit containing battery and a resistor.In that circuit [image]

In above image what is fs  . it is adding to E which means it has to be some kind of Electric field.From where did it come ? That's only my question .Thank you

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to answer your question yourself. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you, and that the Q/A is beneficial for broad audience.   As "homework-like questions" are considered literal homeworks, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.  Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this. See [Homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448).  Otherwise, the question may get closed as "low effort homework-like question."

Comment: I did edit it sir .

Comment: Still no thoughts, reasoning and effort to answer your question. You just more or less summarised your previous question and answer to it. Involve basic knowledge of electrostatics.

Comment: A hint: The beakers/electrode compartments are connected in sense on ion mobility.

Comment: Yes ! by salt bridge .So the ions in these compartment make a Electric field which is directed "due" to excess of Positive ions in one compartment to  lack of Positive ions in other compartment ?

Comment: Does displacement of negative and positive charges create electrostatic field ? Does a field cause charges to move ? Does change of charge displacement affect the field ?